# Reformulation of a problem with piecewise maximum cost into an LP

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the following optimization problem:

\begin{align*}
\min_{x} \; & c^\top x + \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_i \max(d_i^\top x, 0)\\
\mathrm{s.t.} \; & Ax \leq b,
\end{align*}

where $w_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for $i=1,\dots, N$ (i.e., can have both negative and postive values). Because of the piecewise maximum function, I was thinking of using a slack variable and express the optimization problem as follows:

\begin{align*}
\min_{x} \; & c^\top x + \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_i y_i\\
\mathrm{s.t.} \; & Ax \leq b,\\
& y_i \geq d_i^\top x, \; \forall i\\
& y_i \geq 0, \; \forall i.
\end{align*}

I would appreciate your help if you can confirm that this is a correct reformulation.

Comment: Then is the reformulation wrong in that case?

Comment: I presume the last line should be $y_i \ge 0$. I was incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for the correction! Then does that mean the reformulation is correct?

Comment: Looks good to me/